# sistema de estoque - alterar valor do input dinamicamente

Tags: javascript

Galera gostaria que o campo "status" mudasse de valor , caso o valor do campo "quantidade" fosse menor do que 5.

tentei o código abaixo mais não funciona. não sei onde estou errando

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var x = document.getElementById("quantidade")
        function aviso(){
            if(x < 5){
                document.getElementById("status").value = 'Quantidade crítica. Comprar mais!!'
            }else{
                document.getElementById("status").value = 'Em estoque'
            }
        }
    </script>
    <title>teste</title>
</head>
<body>
    Quantidade: <input type="text"  id="quantidade" onkeyup="aviso()"><br><br>
    status: <input type="text"  id="status"><br><br>                    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tens de obter o `value` do elemento `x` a cada chamada da função `aviso`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>teste</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function aviso(){
            let x = document.getElementById("quantidade").value
            console.log(x)
            if(x < 5) {
                document.getElementById("status").value = 'Quantidade crítica. Comprar mais!!'
            } else {
                document.getElementById("status").value = 'Em estoque'
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Quantidade: <input type="text"  id="quantidade" onkeyup="aviso()"><br><br>
    status: <input type="text"  id="status"><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Para além disso, adicionei a tag `meta` para mostrar correctamente os caracteres especiais tais como `í`.

Comment: obrigado @chriptus13, funciona somente quando comparo x com um numero. quando comparo com uma variável y, só funciona na iteração. sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: Não esqueça marcar como correcta.